# Changing Default File Manager in Ubuntu Gnome 18.04.2

Tags: nemo

...in Ubuntu Gnome 18.04.2

Dolphin doesn't tick all my boxes and I much rather prefer using Nemo.

In the Kubuntu you can set this under default applications, not in the Gnome  DE. How can this be done?